# Recursion running through infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I just started out with recursion so I was solving a question which is like

> Create a function that takes numbers as arguments, adds them together, and returns the product of digits until the answer is only 1 digit long.

```
sumDigProd(16, 28) ➞ 6
// 16 + 28 = 44
// 4 * 4 =  16
// 1 * 6 = 6

sumDigProd(0) ➞ 0

sumDigProd(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ➞ 2
```

so i did it with recursion as

```
function sumDigProd(...digits) {
  let ans = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(ans);
  const result=calc(ans);
 function calc(ans) {
    ans = ans.toString();
    let pro = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
      pro = pro * ans[i];
    }
    console.log(pro);
    while (pro > 10) {
      calc(pro);
    }
    return pro
   
  }
  return result
}
console.log(sumDigProd(16,28));
```

so I am running it in infinite loop

Comment: This doesn't require recursion.

Comment: What is `sevenBoom()`?

Comment: but how i can only think of recursion as a solution to this

Comment: @kmoser sorry type error

Comment: You don't assign the return value from the recursive call. It should be assigned to `pro`.

Comment: You can do this using a simple while loop or using recursion

Comment: @Jack yeah tried by recursion just wanna now why it's going in infinte loop :(

Comment: You need a base condition to exit the recursive call o.w. you will end up with memory overflow issues

Comment: Actually there is a base case. It happens when pro is < 10. Which is also an issue. The while condition should be `>= 10`. Since there is recursion, the `while` could be just be an `if`. And `pro = calc(pro)`.

Comment: @trincot tried that but still infinite loop

Comment: Well the most simple issue is that you're not setting pro when running calc in the while loop. Replace `calc(pro)` with `pro = calc(prop)`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the signature of the function because it is supposed to get a number rather then a list of numbers so you initial argument and the following arguments are inconsistent if you fix the signature approving my thought I can help you with the answer

Comment: @nikoss, read the assignment. The initial call is with a list of numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not assign the return value from the recursive call.

Also, you are mixing an iterative solution (with `while`) with a recursive one. You need one of the two, not both.

For the recursive solution you can just use an `if`. And in that case you can even immediately return the return value from the recursive call.

Also, the condition should be `pro >= 10`, as 10 is not OK as a final value:

```js
function sumDigProd(...digits) {
  let ans = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(ans);

  function calc(ans) {
    ans = ans.toString();
    let pro = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
      pro = pro * ans[i];
    }
    console.log(pro);
    if (pro >= 10) {
      return calc(pro); // recursive case
    }
    return pro; // base case
  }

  return calc(ans);
}
console.log(sumDigProd(16,28));
```

An iterative solution could be achieved with little change:

```js
function sumDigProd(...digits) {
  let pro = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(pro);

  while (pro >= 10) {
    ans = pro.toString();
    pro = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
      pro = pro * ans[i];
    }
    console.log(pro);
  }

  return pro;
}
console.log(sumDigProd(16,28));
```

And crunching the code to a smaller footprint, it could become:

```js
function sumDigProd(...digits) {
  let pro = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  while (pro >= 10) {
    pro = Array.from(pro.toString()).reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
  }
  return pro;
}
console.log(sumDigProd(16,28));
```

Comment: thanks it worked...but any case this can be done with while loop ?

Comment: can u update the code ? actually that was what i was looking for....with while loop..sorry that i didnt mention it clearly

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could return the result of calling `calc` for getting a recursive result.

```js
function sumDigProd(...digits) {
    function calc(ans) {
        let pro = [...ans.toString()].reduce((a, b) => a * b);
        return pro > 9 
            ? calc(pro)
            : pro;
    }

    return calc(digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
}

console.log(sumDigProd(16, 28)); // 6
console.log(sumDigProd(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign `pro` and change your `while` to an `if`:

```js
function sumDigProd(...digits) {
  let ans = digits.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(ans);
  const result=calc(ans);
 function calc(ans) {
    ans = ans.toString();
    let pro = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
      pro = pro * ans[i];
    }
    console.log(pro);
    if (pro >= 10) {
      pro = calc(pro);
    }
    return pro

  }
  return result
}
console.log(sumDigProd(16,28,12));
```

Comment: Ah, @trincot snuck in the same answer while I was composing mine!

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter version:

```
function sumDigProd(a, b){

  let rec = function(a) {
    if (String(a).length == 1) return a;
        return rec(String(a).split('').map(Number).reduce((a,b)=>a*b));
  }
   return rec(a+b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Editorial: I found some of the answers here clever, but harder to follow, below is another example of adding the values, and then multiplying digits if there are multiple*

---

## Recursive: Product of Sum's Digits

```js
const sumDigitProduct = (num,...rest)=>{

  if(rest.length)
    num = sumDigitProduct( rest.reduce((agg,cv)=>agg+parseFloat(cv), num) )
  
  const digits = (''+num).split('')
  if( digits.length > 1)
    num = sumDigitProduct( digits.reduce((agg,cv)=>agg*parseFloat(cv)) )
  
  return num;
};


// Tests
console.log('expect: 3; got:', sumDigitProduct(1,2))
console.log('expect: 5; got:', sumDigitProduct(15))
console.log('expect: 6; got:', sumDigitProduct(16,28))
console.log('expect: 0; got:', sumDigitProduct(0))
console.log('expect: 2; got:', sumDigitProduct(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: Note, you don't really need recursion, this is forcing something that can easily be removed and function the same (if not more efficiently)